# What is the source of this hadith about sitting on a grave?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request, grave

Where is this hadith written? Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said, "It is much better for one of you to sit on a live coal, which will burn his clothes and get to his skin than to sit on a grave."

I tried looking in http://hadithcollection.com/ but I can't find it. I need to know the exact location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hadith is narrated in several collections including [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/11/124),
[Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/21/140), [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1289160), [Sunan Nisai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2044) in their كتاب الجنائز (Book of Funerals)

The wording related by Muslim are:

> عن أبي هريرة قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لأن يجلس أحدكم على جمرة فتحرق ثيابه فتخلص إلى جلده خير له من أن يجلس على قبر
>
> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
>
> It is better that one of you should sit on live coals which would burn his clothing and come in contact with his skin than that he should sit on a grave.